# Erratic Ajaxing with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

By default jQueryMobile is supposed to ajax new pages. However the behaviour I am seeing is erratic. Sometimes it works and sometimes (e.g. the next day) it does full page refreshes.

My links are absolutely normal local links to the same page: `<a href="./default.htm?a=123>Link 123</a>`, no `rel="external"` no $.mobile.options set etc.

Currently, I'm using Chrome and it's not doing ajax. The exact same application in IE9 is doing ajax (with # history). But I have seen Chrome do ajax (yesterday). If I debug it actually goes into a $.ajax() function for my link but the result still is that the whole page is refreshed.

My question is this: under what circumstances (except those stated above) does jQueryMobile (v1.1.1) fallback to non-ajax page refreshes?

I suspect some browser check or other exception is causing ajax to be circumvented.

Comment: I can confirm it's not dependant on my application but on the browser. With the official jQueryDocs (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html) it is the same: Chrome does full page refreshes, IE is ajaxing.

Comment: I can also confirm that in Chrome, where ajax is not happening,  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true.

Also, no ajax is happening on the iPhone on my app and on jQueryMobile.com - this must be a 1.1.1. issue...

Comment: I'm sort of running into a similar issue. While my page works on iPad1 (ios3) when I start the app through the home-screen icon, pages are refreshed and not loaded. I have been trying to trace this down yesterday and ended up here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8412 although it's not really my case, since I'm not using app cache and still experience the same behavior. Still a little cluesless. I tried the propsed fixes (setting isLocal on docReady), but this only changes xhr.readystate from 0 to 4 with an empty Ajax response. Still searching for reasons.

Comment: I've posted it as an issue (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4867). In all browsers but IE9 there is no ajax or page injection going on for me. Even on the official JQM Docs site!!